# Execute Returned Data as Expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I have a (shared) dataset that, when selected via

```
=First(Fields!TableColumn.Value, "DatasetName")
```

will return something similar to

```
=IIF(ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 2, "WHITE", "WHITESMOKE")
```

I am trying to use this such that I can have multiple reports with dynamic, expression based formatting (mainly in row background color) that I can update by modifying a single record in a dataset. The issue is that Report Builder does not seem to want to execute this code, and instead interprets it as a escaped string. Is there any way to specify this should be executed as an expression?

I've tried:

```
=IIF(ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 2, "WHITE", "WHITESMOKE")
IIF(ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 2, "WHITE", "WHITESMOKE")
"=IIF(ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 2, "WHITE", "WHITESMOKE")" 
"IIF(ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 2, "WHITE", "WHITESMOKE")"
```

Comment: I am curious, what ever made you think that any of this would work how you describe? Have you used some other reporting tool that does this?

Comment: @R.Richards Well, currently if it returns something like "WHITE" or "GREEN" it will color the background accordingly. It seemed like this would be included functionality (as it's not that big of a step), and as I would imagine a ten-thousand person corporation would not want to have to go through and manually change the formula on all ten thousand reports every time someone decided to update the formatting guidelines. That being said, I have been wrong before! Is this not supported functionality, to the best of your knowledge?

Comment: It's a forward thinking idea to try and corral your formatting before you get to that 10,000 report repository.  I've had times I wished I'd enforced stuff like this more in the past

Comment: I agree with Daniel, trying to get ahead of this is a good train of thought. But, what you are attempting here is not supported functionality in SSRS. I tend to do this sort of thing in the SQL by returning a `bg` column with the color name in it (much like Daniel's answer). You can be as flexible as you like there without having to change any RDL later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that SSRS will interpret your field value as an expression and will instead always treat it as a string.

However, to achieve what you are looking to do, what about breaking this up into smaller pieces.

Shared dataset named "colors":

```
SELECT 'WHITE' as color1, 'WHITESMOKE' as color
```

Expression for background color:

```
=IIF(
   ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 2,
   First(Fields!Color1.Value, "Colors"), 
   First(Fields!Color2.Value, "Colors"))
```

Comment: That works as a nice workaround, and appears to be the closest I can get to my desired functionality. Thank you!